# Auto absolute block width in small container

Tags: html, css

Then i add some text in my absolute block inner div it dosn't expand.

I know that exapanding forbids a parent container width: `<div class="main_wrap"></div>`.

But I can't remove it from him.
So i want to find a solution how i can correct it without a js. How can i do this? It must to expand in width, not in height, talking about this element: `<div class="abs">`. IF you remove a width from `.main_wrap` it's correct view, but i need to reach results like this without removing width, because it's just little part of huge grid.

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="abs">
      <table class="whf table">
          <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="image">
                  <div class="shadow"></div>
                  <img src="http://boardingarea.com/blogs/deltapoints/files/2012/07/test.jpg" width="77" />
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="vamid">
                  <div class="text">
                      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
```

Here is full example:

http://jsbin.com/uqafuq/6/edit

Thanks in future.

Comment: could you please reiterate your question, I don't understand

Comment: Yes, you are right, not enought clear: my abs div and table should expand to width.

Comment: Found a solution but didn't say what it was, voted down

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly and your construction looks quite strange, but is this what you wanted to achieve? http://jsbin.com/uqafuq/11/edit

Just remove the `height: 100%` from `.abs`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your `height: 100%` from `.abs` your setting your height from the elements parent which dont have height at all

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.block`